# Can placeholders be used with fgets?

Tags: c, string, fgets

Is it illegal to use placeholders within a call to `fgets`?

For example, I have written the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char input[32], name_first[16], name_last[16];

    if (fgets(input, 32, stdin) == "My name is %s %s")
    {
        sscanf(input, "My name is %s %s", &name_first, &name_last);
        printf("Your name is %s %s", name_first, name_last);
    }
    else
        printf("What?");

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I think it's pretty straightforward to see what I'm trying to do with the program. If you type the sentence, "My name is," the program will display "Your name is," followed by the first one or two words you type afterwards.

I wrote this as practice for using `fgets()` and `sscanf()` in place of `scanf()`, but now I'm kind of curious to see if I can expand on that.

Comment: I think you're confused what `str1 == str2` does if `str1` and `str2` are declared as `char*`.

Comment: Is your question actually about why this program always displays `What?`, no matter what your input is?

Comment: you simply cant use `%s` and other placeholders with `fgets`

Comment: You should read [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: Remember to terminate lines of output with newlines; the printing doesn't usually appear until you do output a newline.

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare strings with `fgets` like that. Its syntax isn't illegal, but it doens't work as you expected. First, using `==` to compare strings will only compare the pointers. Second, `%s` has no special meaning in a simple string. Here's what you should do:

Get the line with `fgets`. Use `sscanf` to get the names. Check for the return value of `sscanf` to see if the match is successful. If it succeeds, the return value should be `2`, indicating 2 numbers of items are matched.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `==` to compare strings, and certainly not to do pattern matching on them.

This:

```
if (fgets(input, 32, stdin) == "My name is %s %s")
```

tests whether the pointer returned by `fgets()` points to *the same address* as the string literal `"My name is %s %s"`. It certainly does not.

You can use the `strcmp()` function to compare strings for equality, but that doesn't do the kind of pattern matching you're looking for.

Just call `fgets()` to store a line (and check the return value to see if there was an error).

You're already using `sscanf`. You just need to check whether it succeeded. It returns the number of items it was able to read. In this case, a return value of 2 indicates success.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main(void)
{
    char input[32], name_first[16], name_last[16];

    if (NULL != fgets(input, 32, stdin) &&
        2 == sscanf(input, "My name is %s %s", &name_first, &name_last) )
    {
        printf("Your name is %s %s", name_first, name_last);
    }
    else
        printf("What?");

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```